# On google site, html cannot work with error code 502

Tags: javascript, html

I made a Google site for my internal use.
On this site, one page was not suitable for iPhone so I made it in HTML and JavaScript.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="./isIphone.js"></script>
     <title>Check iPhone</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body onload="isIphone()"></body>
</html>
```

and JavaScript code as below:

```
function isIphone() {
  var osVer = "iPhone";
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf(osVer) > 0) {
    var childWindow =
       window.open('https://calendar.google.com/calendar/');
  }
  else {
    var childWindow = window.open('https://xxxxxxx/calendar/main');
  }
}
```

Above code worked fine until last week, but from yesterday it does not anymore and produce error code `502`.

Comment: which page gives you the 502 error?

Comment: try clearing all your cache,etc and try to run again. 502 sometime can be tricky to debug. remove all cache,etc as a first measure

Comment: `A server (not necessarily a Web server) is acting as a gateway or proxy to fulfil the request by the client to access the requested URL. This server received an invalid response from an upstream server it accessed.

This usually does not mean that the upstream server is down, but rather that the upstream server and the gateway/proxy do not agree on the protocol for exchanging data. Given that Internet protocols are quite clear, it often means that one or both machines have been incorrectly or incompletely programmed.` - http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E502.html

Comment: Can you open this [link](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/) in your regular browser ?

Comment: Thank you MaxZoom.

Comment: Thank you for your comments!  I clear all my cache, then they work.